# Jupyter kernel crash when querying dataframe with Period datatype

Tags: pandas, datetime, crash, jupyter-notebook

I've come across an interesting problem. I have a dataset with three columns with dates stored as integers in the format YYYYMM. First, I tried converting them to datetime, but some of the dates are outside of the 1677-09-21 lower bound for a datetime datatype. So I used the workaround [in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-oob) as such:

```
def conv(x):
    return pd.Period( year=x // 10000, month=x // 100 % 100, day=x % 100, freq='D' )

# First, append '01' to create format YYYYMMDD, then apply conversion function
columns = ['indep_date', 'cow_system_ind_date', 'gw_system_ind_date']
for column in columns:
   icow[column] = ( icow[column].astype('str') + '01' ).astype('int').apply(conv)
```

This all works fine. After applying this function, however, I can no longer make a selection of my dataframe by querying any columns. If I try any of these, the Jupyter kernel crashes:

```
icow.query( 'column != 200' )
icow[ icow['col1'] != icow['col2'] ]
icow[ icow['col1'].ne( icow['col2'] ) ]
```

I tried a variety of other methods, but all result in a crash and restart of the kernel. The interesting thing is if I just run the internal part, it runs fine. For instance:

```
icow['col1'] != icow['col2']
```

properly returns a series of True/False values. As soon as I wrap it to try to get back a selection of the dataframe, crash.

If I drop the period[D] columns (or skip the conversion), my queries run fine. Anyone know why having these period[D] datatypes in my dataframe would cause this problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** The problem is that one of the three date columns contained a number of entries with -9 in the original dataset. Interestingly, the function to convert the string representations to Period didn't fail, but it corrupted the dataframe in some way that made queries against any column cause a kernel crash. By setting -9 dates to a far past date of 0001-01-01, everything works properly.